# Best approach to execute a long running task in asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, quartz.net

I am working on an asp.net mvc5 web application + Entity framework 6.0 deployed inside IIS 7.0. currently i have a NetworkScanning server which I implemented as a normal action method , that  can be started in 2 ways :-

1.based on a schedule defined inside the global.asax:-

```
static void ScheduleTaskTrigger()
        {
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("ScheduledTaskTrigger",
                                  string.Empty,
                                  null,
                                  Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
                                  TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Double.Parse(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScanInMinutes"])), // as defined inside the web.config
                                  CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
                                  new CacheItemRemovedCallback(PerformScheduledTasks));
        }

        static void PerformScheduledTasks(string key, Object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
        {
            //Your TODO
            HomeController h = new HomeController();
            var c = h.ScanNetwork("***", "allscan");
            ScheduleTaskTrigger();
        }
```

2.or manually calling the action method from the user browser.

now the action method looks as follow (i removed a lot of code as the idea is to give a hint on what i am doing inside the action method):-

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ScanNetwork(string token, string FQDN) 
        {
            string TToken = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TToken"];//get the T token from the web.config, this should be encrypted
            var cccc = Request == null ? System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TIP"] : Request.UserHostAddress;
            if (token != TToken || cccc != System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TIP"]) 
            {


                if (FQDN != "allscan")
                { return Json(new { status = "fail", message = "Authintication failed." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); }
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(403, "request failed");
            }

            try
            {

              scaninfo = await repository.populateScanInfo(false); // get the info for all the servers from the database



                using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
                {
                    string url = currentURL + "resources?AUTHTOKEN=" + pmtoken;
                    var json = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
                    resourcesinfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResourcesInfo>(json);
                }


                foreach (var c in scaninfo) //loop through all the hypervisot server/s
                {


                    if (passwordmanagerResource.Count() == 0) // if there is not any record for the resource on the password manager
                    {


                       await repository.Save();
                        continue;

                    }
                    else if (passwordmanagerResource.Count() > 1) // if more than on record is defined for the same resource on PM
                    {


                        await repository.Save();
                        continue;

                    }
                    else
                    {



                        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) // call the PM API to get the account id 
                        {
                            string url = currentURL + "resources/" + passwordmanagerResourceID + "/accounts?AUTHTOKEN=" + pmtoken;
                            var json = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);

                            resourceAccountListInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResourceAccountListInfo>(json);
                        }

                        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) // call the PM API to get the password for the account id under the related resource
                        {
                            string url = currentURL + "resources/" + passwordmanagerResourceID + "/accounts/" + passwordmanagerAccountID + "/password?AUTHTOKEN=" + pmtoken;
                            var json = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
                            resourceAccountPasswordListInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResourceAccountPasswordInfo>(json);
                        }

                        var shell = PowerShell.Create();
                        var shell2 = PowerShell.Create();
                        var shell3 = PowerShell.Create();

                        //Powercli script to get the hypervisot info
                        string PsCmd = "add-pssnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core; $vCenterServer = '" + vCenterName + "';$vCenterAdmin = '" + vCenterUsername + "' ;$vCenterPassword = '" + vCenterPassword + "';" + System.Environment.NewLine;



                        PsCmd = PsCmd + "$VIServer = Connect-VIServer -Server $vCenterServer -User $vCenterAdmin -Password $vCenterPassword;" + System.Environment.NewLine;



                        PsCmd = PsCmd + "Get-VMHost " + System.Environment.NewLine;

                        string PsCmd2 = "add-pssnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core; $vCenterServer = '" + vCenterName + "';$vCenterAdmin = '" + vCenterUsername + "' ;$vCenterPassword = '" + vCenterPassword + "';" + System.Environment.NewLine;



                        PsCmd2 = PsCmd2 + "$VIServer = Connect-VIServer -Server $vCenterServer -User $vCenterAdmin -Password $vCenterPassword;" + System.Environment.NewLine;



                        PsCmd2 = PsCmd2 + " Get-VMHost " + vCenterName + "| Get-VMHostNetworkAdapter -VMKernel" + System.Environment.NewLine;



                        shell.Commands.AddScript(PsCmd);
                        shell2.Commands.AddScript(PsCmd2);
                        dynamic results = shell.Invoke(); // execute the first powercli script
                        dynamic results2 = shell2.Invoke();//execute the second powercli script


                        if (results != null && results.Count > 0 && results[0].BaseObject != null) // the powercli executed successfully
                        {
                            // call the service desk API to update the hypervisor info
                            var builder = new StringBuilder();

                            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                            using (var client = new WebClient())
                            {

                                var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);


                              //code goes here

                                string xml = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url.ToString());

                                doc.LoadXml(xml);
                                status = doc.SelectSingleNode("/operation/operationstatus").InnerText;
                                message = doc.SelectSingleNode("/operation/message").InnerText;


                            }

                        else//if the powershell script return zero result..
                        {

                            c.TServer.ScanResult = "Scan return zero result";
                            scan.Description = scan.Description + "<span style='color:red'>" + c.TServer.ScanResult + "</span><br/>";
                            await repository.Save();
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (FQDN == "allscan")
                        {

                           //code goes here
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                errormessage = "Password manager or manage engine can not be accessed";
                errorstatus = "fail";

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                errormessage = "scan can not be completed. Message" + e.InnerException;
                errorstatus = "fail";

            }
            scan.EndDate = System.DateTime.Now;


                using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, "*****"))
                {
                    mail.Subject = "scan report generated";
                    //  mail.Body = emailbody;

                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    System.Text.StringBuilder mailBody = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    mailBody.AppendLine("<span style='font-family:Segoe UI'>Hi, <br/>");
                    mailBody.AppendLine(scan.Description);
                    mailBody.AppendLine("<br/><br/><div style='color:#f99406;font-weight:bold'>T scanning Management </div> <br/> <div style='color:#f99406;font-weight:bold'>Best Regards</div></span>");

                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                    smtp.Host = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpIP"];
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    mail.Body = mailBody.ToString();

                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

                    smtp.Port = Int32.Parse(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpPort"]);
                    S
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                }
            }
            return Json(new { status = errorstatus, message = errormessage }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);



        }
```

now as shown on the above action method it contain many operations such as ; retrieve objects from DB , save DB changes, call web clients on third party applications, run powercli scripts , etc.. now i deployed the application on IIS and seems it is working fine, either when it run manually by users or based on the schedule time. but from my own reading is that running long running tasks such as the above action method is considered risky, and i need to use different approach . so can anyone adivce why the above approach is considered risky and how i can improve it ?
second question. now i read that Quartz.NET is an approach to follow, but not sure if i can still call Quartz.NET method from a web browser & not sure if i can call webclient, execute powercli scripts, etc inside Quartz.NET ?

Thanks

Comment: @haim770 but i can not understand what will be the differences if i run the method as an action method or as a hangfire method? now if i call the action method on a timely basis from the global.asax will it be different than calling it using hangfire ? second question if i use hangfire can i still call the method from a web browser.. please can you adivce more ?

Comment: Hangfire is built for these sort of issues, I would not put a timed action in the `global.asax`... Hangfire can come with a UI that you can go and kick off a scheduled task. Look at the documentation and you will realise why you want this.

Comment: @JamieRees now let say i use hangfire or quartz.net to define the network scanning method as a timly job.. and then i deploy my asp.net mvc (which contain the quartz.net job) inside IIS , then will the quartz.net job runs under iis ? or it will run on its own binaries ? if it will run under iis then i will be facing the same risk as calling the action method ,, is this correct ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with quatz so I cannot answer. But yes Hangfire will run under a w3wp in IIS. The whole point in using these tools is so you do not have to build in your own scheduler. They have done the work for you and sorted out the caveats e.g. failed job, retry cycle. Why re-invent the wheel

Comment: Currently inside the global.asax file I define the schedule to call the action method every 3 hours. if i understand your reply well, even using tools such as quatz & hangfire their jobs will be running under iis, but the advantages of these tools over using global.asax is that they already provide functionalities for failed job, retry cycle,.?. second question back to my original question, in my case i have what is considered a long running method to scan network,, so is calling this method on timely basis using either hangfire or global.asax considered a good approach  or not?

Answer (score 5):

As someone suggested the alternative to Quartz.Net can be [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/).
This last one is much simpler to implement than Quartz.Net and it's got a beautiful admin dashboard.

Hangfire offers you pretty much the same functionalities of Quartz.Net.

You can bootstrap it in the Owin Startup:

```
var options = new SqlServerStorageOptions
{
    PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = true,
    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)
};

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .UseSqlServerStorage("<your connection string here>", options)
    .UseNLogLogProvider()
    .UseActivator(new StructureMapHangfireJobActivator(My.Application.Container));

app.UseHangfireServer();

app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
{
    AuthorizationFilters = new[] { new BpNetworkSales.Web.Infrastructure.ActionFilters.HangfireDashboardAuthorizationFilter() }
});
```

You can use your preferred logger:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseNLogLogProvider();
```

You can use your favourite DI container:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(new StructureMapHangfireJobActivator(My.Application.Container));
```

and you can easily run recurring tasks:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("RunSyncDocumentsForStatus", () => My.Application.SyncDocumentsForStatus(My.Application.CompanyCode), "0/3 * * * *");
```

schedule delayed job:

```
Hangfire.BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => My.Application.SyncSubmittedDocuments(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

and use attributes to automatic retry the operation:

```
[Hangfire.AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 5)]
public static void SyncSubmittedDocuments()
{
    ...
}
```

or disable concurrent execution:

```
[Hangfire.DisableConcurrentExecution(timeoutInSeconds: 120)]
public static void SyncDocumentsForStatus(string companyCode)
{

}
```

It's just a beautifully designed piece of software; whereas Quartz.Net is a little bit more complicated, especially if you're starting to do "fancy" stuff.

You always have to remember that you're running these tasks inside IIS so when IIS is suspended or recycled your jobs will shut down.

In your previous question [Jay Vilalta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167388/jvilalta) (who knows quite a lot about Quartz.Net) told you that the alternative is to use Quartz.Net as a Windows Service.

I guess if you're planning to schedule long, recurring jobs which you want to run at a specific time and you want to be 100% sure they're going to be executed, well, the Windows Service is the best option you have.

The other advantage is your ASP.NET MVC application will be smoother as you won't have other background tasks which will be running while the user is doing is daily job.

If you are not familiar with Windows Services I would suggest to go for [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) which has got an [integration](https://github.com/dtinteractive/Topshelf.Integrations) for Quartz.Net.

Comment: thanks for the very helpful reply. so now i understand that using quartz.net or hangfire inside my asp.net web application is not the right approach or is not the most robust approach because they still run under iis. and it is preferred to write my long running task as a windows service. So now inside my action method i am doing these types of tasks; running power-shell scripts, using entity framework,web client , etc..

Comment: so will windows service offers these functionalities ? as i did not write any windows service before, and i am not sure if writing a windows service is similar to writing an action method inside asp.net mvc?

Comment: If you have control of your server and you can install whatever you want Windows Services are the best approach. You can run the service under an administrative account so, potentially, you can do whatever you fancy. These days you can use [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) which makes things easier.

Comment: so now on this link http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/ it mentioned that the most robust approach is to have long running tasks a windows service, but at the same time the link offers some tools which can make running long running tasks inside iis more robust the link mentioned "...the second reason is for simplicity. If you’re ok with the limitations I mentioned, this approach has one less moving part to worry about when setting up a website. There’s no need to configure an external recurring task. It just works.....

Comment: becuase in my case everything i want is already inside my asp.net mvc, and i did not write any windows service before,, so i am trying to find an approach that can make executing a long running taks inside iis possible , and seems there are tools that can improve the robustness of this .but will not provide the 100% robustness offered by windows service. what do u think ?

Comment: I have used both Quartz.Net and Hangfire running in my ASP.NET MVC app and I am pretty happy with that. These days I only use Hangfire cause it's much simpler and it works really well. With my tasks (jobs) I am not worried if the server (IIS) goes down or if the process is recycled. They just need to run when one user bootstraps the application. I do not run powershell scripts though. Your app pool need to have privileges to do that, I guess ... hence the need of windows services.

Comment: If you're happy with the answer could you, please, accept it? Cheers.

Comment: but i am a bit confused , now you mentioned the following "...You always have to remember that you're running these tasks inside IIS so when IIS is suspended or recycled your jobs will shut down...." , but will this also happens if i use hangfire? because you also mentioned " ...am not worried if the server (IIS) goes down or if the process is recycled. They just need to run when one user bootstraps the application..." ,, so will using hangfire prevent my method from being suspended if the IIs goes down or the process is recycled ?? i am a bit confused ?

Comment: I guess you have to first understand how things work. I would suggest to read [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) and [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) and [this](http://discuss.hangfire.io/t/how-to-make-a-background-job-run-where-it-stopped-when-app-pool-was-recycled/115).